# Request, does not contain handler parameter, Maximum number of parameters limit in a post

Tags: java, struts1, parameters-limit

I'm working on a struts based application. On a page I'm sending a dynamic form with POST request that takes number of parameters(Radio buttons & hidden form fields). When i click on submit button it show a blank white page. I investigated the issue on chrome and found that it is giving an exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Request[/MMSP] does not contain handler parameter named 'form_action'.  This may be caused by whitespace in the label text.
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:446)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Request[/MMSP] does not contain handler parameter named 'form_action'.  This may be caused by whitespace in the label text.
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.unspecified(DispatchAction.java:194)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:242)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:167)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:53)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:64)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:48)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:280)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:446)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

To make sure that handler parameter is provided i check it in the JSP page and that was provided.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="funcName">
```

But still I'm getting this error. My question is related to POST parameter limitation for number of parameters as this request takes more then 600 parameters with it. Is there any possibility that request missing the last few parameters causing this issue.

Note: My application is deployed on Tomcat-8 we recently upgraded the Tomcat version from 7 to 8.

Comment: which browser you are using

Comment: Chrome is the browser

Comment: earlier tomcat version it was working fine...??

Comment: Yes but im not sure Tomcat version change is the reason, might be that is not the reason

Comment: possible to get the complete url size (in kb, MB), also try in any other broswer, any new parameter added in form along with tomcat upgradation

Comment: can you post your `server.xml`

Comment: no, because this error is in production environment and i don't have access to server.xml file, i check it in some other browser and also for server.xml file if i find it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111819/discussion-between-ankur-singhal-and-noname).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Test the maxPostSize value of the new Tomcat